# Change status according to payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, order-state

I am working on magento 1.9

My requirement based on which payment method user use to make payment,

**Status should change Automatically**

Cash on delivery - when user place an order cash on delivery

Online Payment Received - when you through payment online, when the status is successful

Online Payment Failed - when the parameter does not match or any error from the payment gateway

Online Payment Cancelled - when user close the payment page or cancel the payment on their own

Cancelled - when user cancel the order from my account

I have had use magento inbuilt feature to change status and assign it to state, with system > order statuses. but the state new only describe the 'new order', i want to create state which tells order as 'new with payment method'

Please guide.

Regards
Lalit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont find any solution though, But got a method for Cash on delivery and Online Payment Statuses.

If a user Selects Cash on delivery method, It uses Magento Default CASH on Delivery Method

[image]

Here on This Method we have an option to Add default status when new order arrives through this method, So we create a status from Magento backend by navigating through admin panel->system->Order Statuses
 or from [this method](http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-order-state/),
and assign the status as default status for new orders through this method,

Same thing Applies with Online Payment Process:

Now when it comes to Online Payment Failed and Online Payment Cancelled, How do i get to know how the payment got cancelled, Any Idea?